# Jsoup find elements with multiple text keywords

Tags: select, jsoup, contains

I'm currently searching Elements with keywords with:

```
doc.select("p:contains(keyword)").get(0);
```

But how can I find elements which contain two keywords?
I need something like:

```
doc.select("p:contains(keyword1 & keyword2).get(0);
```

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

Below given statement can be used for multiple selectors.

```
doc.select("p:contains(keyword1):contains(keyword2)")
```